# how to make a value between parentheses in a text file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

How can i get value contained in a text file in parentheses?

Example Input:

```
Today is a beautiful {day}
```

I want to get the value of `day`.

Comment: Can you add more details? For example, are you trying to use a script? Are you trying to change an existing file? Or are you reading the file for the variable? I'm just not sure what you're asking...

Comment: Ho leanne, thanks forum replay. I m trying use script that read a file .txt and save in a variabile the value  between parenthese.

Comment: is there just (exactly) one such marked word in the file? If no, which one do you need? First? Last? All of them in different variables?

Comment: I solved it alone thanks to everyone!

Comment: then put an answer (and accept it) or delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

if you wanted to get the day, you could do `%day%`, which would print the variable day instead of writing day

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, your question is not very exact, so I try my best to answer, what you asked for, assuming there is just one line and there is exactly one `{...}` part and it's not at the very beginning of the string:

```
set "string=Today is a beautiful {day}"
for /f "tokens=2 delims={}" %%a in ("%string%") do set "var=%%a"
echo %var%
```